# Silver stipe 4.5 add css in admin create pages

Tags: silverstripe

Is it possible to include a link to a custom css stylesheet in the CMS at admin created particular pages in silverstipe 4.5 ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can add custom css even custom javascript to the CMS, you can do it via YML.

```
SilverStripe\Admin\LeftAndMain:
  extra_requirements_css:
    - app/css/BookmarkedPages.css
```

Please check this documentation https://docs.silverstripe.org/en/4/developer_guides/customising_the_admin_interface/how_tos/extend_cms_interface/#include-custom-css-in-the-cms